# How to approve follow requests through code in twitter API?

Tags: java, api, twitter, request

People have to register and follow my tweets...
I need people to request following my ID and I need to approve them by using API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to approve people who have requested me to follow and I need this done by API.
I have currently figured a way out of this problem.
(Twitter has not implemented the API call for this)

1. I will un-protect my tweets and people need not send request to follow me.
2. I will make people to follow me through an web based application that stores the User_ID in the db.
3. I will run periodic script that compares the followers in the application to followers in the twitter ID.
4. I will block the user who is has not been registered through my web based application.
5. I will un-block them once they do not follow me/ register through my application.

Please comment on this solution

Answer (score 0):

why not try a twitter api library for java

http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/

http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

any one of the above libraries would help.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Twitter4J and I am asking is there an API call to confirm requested users to my account?